# Trying to superimpose a face onto a smurf

Tags: gimp

So I've removed Papa smurfs face, and I've pasted the face over the photo so I can grab the exact part that I cut out of the smurf's face to superimpose. But everytime I paste I just get the smurf face back and not the selection shape of the face, but from the photograph.

(I found it hard to search what I'm trying to do, because I am not even an amateur at this)

Essentially I want to use the shape of my selection to select on the photo.

What I've done sofar is change my paste layer's opacity to 0. But as soon as I anchor it into the image, the selection shape disappears.

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing what's happening. So you copy a selection from the photo with the face, then you paste it onto the smurf. After pasting, you are seeing the face and can move it around and such, but when you deselect the paste layer, it vanishes. Is that correct? It *sounds* like layer or selection thing. I'd make sure I had the right layers selected and explicitly clear selections in both before trying again. (+1 btw for the question title alone)

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Layer selection issue.

Comment: So I copied the smurf's face to see which part I want to take out, and then I had a shape that would fit the Smuf's face perfectly.  I wanted to use this shape to just copy from the photo and then I know the two would fit well.  I've now watched a youtube vid, and well, essentially I can't select on the smurf I have to select on the photo, but I can change the Opacity of the two so I can outline on the smurf face, but actually be selecting on the photo. I feel there is probably a better way, but it worked for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

I copy the face using the Oval (faces are kinda oval), and paste it into the Smurf picture I wanted to superimpose my people onto. The faces are usually vastly bigger than I want (photo's vs internet picture), so I resized the face, as well as rotate or even transform the face until the eyes of the person and the eyes of the smurfs roughly matched, and in terms of size that their chins roughly overlapped.

Smurfs' faces are significantly rounder, so sometimes I would let the human chin drop over where the smurf chin was.

Once the scale and position of the human face layer is where I'm happy, I set the layer's opacity lower (between 50 and 70). The enabled me to see where I want to chop off the human face to keep the smurf cap/glasses etc. Important to keep fingers etc that was in front of the smurf face also in front of the human face.

Remember to invert your selection, and then delete the non-face part of the human layer.

The result obviously is still *very* amateur, but came out OK. I'll paste a imagebin/imgur/etc if the human faces says its OK.

Comment: I also later changed the color levels to make everyone's faces more blue.